# XSL add a duration (exslt date)

Tags: xslt, exslt

I have an xsl where I want to display a default expiry date (now+1 month)

I can display the current date with this (using: xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date")

```
<xsl:variable name="currentdate" select="date:date()"/>
<!-- add one month to $currentdate-->
<xsl:value-of select="date:format-date($currentdate, 'MM/yy')"/>
```

the problem I am having is that i can not seem to a time period to currentdate. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've missed [EXSLT - date:add](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/add/index.html).

Comment: i missed that it is a template i have to download and include first... thanks :)